# Unable to obtain a connection to Hyperion Essbase

Tags: hyperion, essbase

**Problem:**

Whenever I do a database refresh in `Hyperion Planning` it hangs in the 21st step and produces the following error. Could anyone please say why this issue causes and the way to resolve it ? Great Help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you carry out a **cube refresh** and in the same time start accessing forms. When you perform a cube refresh make sure it **completes**. If and only if it completes start accessing the forms. Then you can isolate this problem without any cases. Sometimes it may take a long time to complete **cube refresh** if *huge number of users* are on the system working.